# Sql table filter?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have  a table ABC

```
 Id      Sub_id      Date

CS01032 Sub012  2011-09-21 16:29:58.853
CS01033 Sub013  2011-09-21 16:30:09.863
CS01033 Sub014  2011-09-21 16:30:12.113
CS01034 Sub015  2011-09-21 16:37:57.233
CS01035 Sub016  2011-09-21 16:51:52.527
CS01035 Sub017  2011-09-21 16:51:54.430
CS01035 Sub018  2011-09-21 16:51:56.333
```

i want filter this  table data  like

```
 Id      Sub_id      Date

CS01032 Sub012  2011-09-21 16:29:58.853 
CS01033 Sub014  2011-09-21 16:30:12.113
CS01034 Sub015  2011-09-21 16:37:57.233    
CS01035 Sub018  2011-09-21 16:51:56.333
```

means  distinct  id with   top 1 sub_id  order by  Date time

Comment: Just mentioning...this shouldn't ever happen, id should be unique.

Answer (score 3):

Use a CTE and the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
;WITH TopData AS
( 
    SELECT  Id, Sub_Id, Date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date DESC) AS 'RowNum')
    FROM
       dbo.ABC
)
SELECT Id, Sub_Id, Date
FROM TopData
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

The CTE (Common Table Expression) will "partition" your data by `Id` and give each group's entries `ROW_NUMBER` values, starting at 1, order by Date descending (newest date first). The first entry for each group - the most recent for each `Id` - has `RowNum = 1`